# Filter array by select option

Tags: typescript

I have a problem with filtering array depending select option's value. Here is the example:

```
<select (change)="filterSelect($event.target.value)">
   <option value="U">U</option>
   <option value="R">R</option>
</select>
```

Here in typescript:

```
 filterLocations(value: any) {

    if (value == "U") {
      this.filterRegion = this.branchRegion;
      this.filterRegion.pop();
    } else {
      this.filterRegion = this.branchRegion;
      this.filterRegion = this.branchRegion.filter(region => region == value);
    }
  }
```

Here is a object:

```
export enum BranchRegion {
  A = "A",
  B = "B",
  C = "C",
  R = "R"
}
```

What i want is when i choose "R" select option should be only "R". And choose "U" select option should be "A, B, C". What i am doing wrong ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use [Array.slice()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) and [Array.join()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) in one case and simply use the `value` in the other case. This would look as follows:

```
filterLocations(value: any) {
    if (value == "U") {
      this.filterRegion = this.branchRegion.slice(0, -1).join(', ');
    } else {
      this.filterRegion = value;
    }
}
```